1/ f noise of PSD behavior in Amplitude Spectrum Density
I‘m a bit confused:
Assume that I have sampled a voltage signal and take the PSD of it, the units are in V^2/Hz.
If it has flicker noise or 1/f noise in its spectrum I would see it as a function decreasing as 10dB/decade.
If I want to display it now as the Amplitude Spectrum density I would take the square root of the PSD and eventually end up with units as V/sqrt(Hz).
Correct me if I’m wrong but the same 1/f noise in the PSD would now decrease as 5dB/decade in ASD.
My confusion originates now from the fact that in typical plots of flicker noise in nV/sqrt(Hz) the function also decreases as 10dB/decade.

No it would still be 10 dB/decade. When it is a magnitude quantity (as it would be after taking the square root), we use $20\log_{10}(V)$ to compute dB, where $V$ here represents a ratio of voltages. When it is a power quantity (as it would be before taking the square root), we use  $10\log_{10}(P)$ to compute dB, where here $P$ represents a ratio of powers.
This is because dB by definition is the log form of a ratio of powers, bel specifically is the log (base 10) of a power ratio, and "decibel" is ten times that.  When we have a ratio of magnitudes such as voltages, we can square them to get a ratio of powers, thus the change from 10 to 20 since $10\log_{10}(V^2) = 20\log_{10}(V)$.
So regardless of what units the signal is in, once it is converted to dB, we are always looking at a power ratio with dB specifically, or the power relative to a reference level (with dBm, dBW, dBV, dBFS, etc).
